# Actual size of TEXT field (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

Will a TEXT field use the same storage space in the database no matter if it is empty, got a few characters or filled to the limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual page [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) describes the storage requirements of each datatype for the MyISAM engine in more detail.

```
Data Type   Storage Required
CHAR(M)     M × w* bytes, 0 <= M <= 255
VARCHAR(M)  L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255 bytes
            L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes
TINYTEXT    L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8
TEXT        L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16
```

*w is the number of bytes required for the maximum-length character in the character set

So in conclusion the number of bytes of storage required to store a string in a TEXT column depends on the length of the string. This differs from `CHAR(100)` where the same amount of storage is required regardless of the length of the string stored.

Comment: I think the user means the `TEXT` type in MySQL, described on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html.

Comment: I think the user actually meant that `TEXT` type, and not `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` (though the manual says `TEXT` can be regarded as `VARCHAR` in most respects).

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, he specifically wanted to know about the TEXT column type. I didn't notice that it was capitalized in the title (I was answering based on the body of the question). I'll updated my answer to make it more specific.